Django sessionid cookies disappearing upon refresh
I am using a Django DRF backend with SessionAuthentication and a NextJS frontend. They are hosted on different ports. I am trying to use the django login function to automatically log the user in when creating an account. When I run this, the sessionid and csrf cookie gets saved into cookies but upon refresh they disappear.
Before refresh:
cookies in dev tools
After refresh:
cookies gone after refresh
Relevant settings.py settings:
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'


CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://localhost:3000",
]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = {
    "https://localhost:3000"
}

View used:
class UserView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    decorators = [sensitive_variables('password'), ensure_csrf_cookie]

    @method_decorator(decorators)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        """Create User"""
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            username = serializer.validated_data['username']
            password = serializer.validated_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
            return Response(data={'response': 'Successfully created account'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

Request:
const response = await fetch(`https://127.0.0.1:8000/user/`, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
});

Both django server and NextJS are running on a dev SSL certificate so both have https.

I think we need to see the response of user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)             if user:                 login(request, user)             return Response(data={'response': 'Successfully created account'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)...sorry hard to format in a comment, but you appear to be passing a "success" attr even if the user doesn't authenticate which would mean the session is not saved...specially since return Response(data={'response': 'Successfully created account'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED) is outside of your if user condition

@ViaTech I put the response in the if statement and still have the same problem. I know it's authenticating because a session is being made in the django database.
